# Automatically create and name an Object from a set list

Tags: excel, shapes, vba

I'm currently trying to auto name the objects from a referenced list rather than just have the object text stated in the script.

How do I get the script to reference a separate worksheet called `Process Steps` where the text value is in cell `C7` instead of entering the statement in the script as `Step 1`

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, 100, 50).Select
Selection.Formula = ""
Selection.ShapeRange.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset40
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Step1"
```

Comment: Try `Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Sheets("YourWorksheetName").Range("C7").Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter has already mentioned how to pick up a value from another cell. Taking this a bit ahead.

Please avoid the use of `.Select/.Activate` [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, 100, 50)

    With shp.OLEFormat.Object
        .Formula = ""

        .ShapeRange.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset40

        .ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Process Steps").Range("C7").Value
    End With
End Sub
```